# Read an Excel (.xlsx) file in Sharepoint C# to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to read an Excel file stored on my local system and show it in a gridview.

I have created a visual WebPart to read a Excel file and display it on grid. How can i do it?

I got suggestion from my colleague to use OpenXML, i don't know how to use it. Can anyone suggest me how to go about this. any tutorials or links to guide forward will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the most easiest ways to read the data from excel file is using linq to excel 
here is the link to it 
   http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

here is a short example

```
var book = new ExcelQueryFactory("pathToExcelFile");

var australia = (from x in book.Worksheet() select x).ToList();
```

and then just bind it to your gridview